# How to extract zip file in different directory in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-restful

I'm writing a python (2.7) script that extracts files from a zip file with an encrypted password. For this, I'm using the ZipFile module to extract files in a different directory. I have followed all the answer whatever is mentioned on here. How to extract all the files from the zip file into a different directory?

I have tried to extract all files into different directories but result is: it is creating directory inside the targeted directory.

```
 try:
    with ZipFile(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)) as zf:             
        zf.extractall('/Users/dipak.das/desktop/docs/',None,b'12345')
 except RuntimeError as e:
    print e
```

I expected the output of the above script should extract all files inside path directories.But my code is creating a directory inside docs directories "/Users/dipak.das/desktop/docs/" and extracting all files.

Comment: Yes, absolute paths will be converted to relative paths. This is by design.

Comment: How can I overcome with that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want the files extracted with no subdirectories...

Totally untested but perhaps try something like

```
import os, shutil

destdir = '/Users/dipak.das/desktop/docs/'
with ZipFile(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)) as zf:
  for name in zf.namelist():
    source = zf.open(name, 'r', b'12345')
    destpath = os.path.join(destdir, os.path.basename(name))
    target = open(destpath, 'w')
    shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
    target.close()
```